# BUCLE INFINITO / Try Catch

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo un problema con un try catch. He simplificado el problema, este no es mi código original pero sirve para mostrar la duda.

Quiero que al introducir una letra, en lugar de petar el programa, recoja el error y me vuelva a pedir el identificador, pero en lugar de parar en la línea del scanner se queda en un bucle infinito.

Aquí pongo el código.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean identificadorEncontrado = false;

    do { //BUCLE PARA VOLVER A PEDIR EL IDENTIFICADOR EN CASO DE QUE NO EXISTA TUTORÍA CON DICHO IDENTIFICADOR
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Introduzca el identificador de la pregunta que desea responder.");

        try { // TRY CATCH PARA QUE AL INTRODUCIR UN DATO DISTINTO DE INT NO INTERRUMPA EL
            // PROGRAMA

            identificador = sc.nextInt(); // AQUI SUELO METER UNA LETRA, Y CUANDO EL BUCLE VUELVE A ESTA LINEA NO SE
            // DETIENE, SE FORMA UN BUCLE INFINITO. 100% SEGURO DE QUE PASA POR ESTA
            // LINEA
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("BUCLE INFINITO");
        }

    } while (!identificadorEncontrado);

}

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y en que momento pones identificadorEncontrado en TRUE?

Comment: y a todo esto.. en que lenguaje?

Comment: Uy perdón, en Java jaja

Comment: Lo he comentado antes, este codigo no es el original. Lo he hecho explícitamente para enseñar el error. El identificadorEncontrado lo pongo en TRUE en el código original

Comment: si perfecto, pero en este codigo de ejemplo, ese error es clarisimo. Por lo cual, ese es el problema con este codigo.

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Comment: que por lo menos aca, identificadorEncontrado nunca cambia su valor.. mira la pregunta que te marque como duplicada, fijate si tu problema no viene por ahi

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien entonces. Ese error no es el que estoy preguntando, si no por que al pasar por TRY el programa no se detiene a esperar un nuevo valor por consola

Comment: Bueno... a ver... vos hiciste un ejemplo, que no funciona, con lo cual ya tenemos un problema ahi... porque tu ejemplo no reproduce tu problema original. Luego, te señale otra pregunta que da una respuesta a un problema que muy probablemente sea el tuyo. La leiste?

Comment: Acabo de leer la pregunta que me has puesto. No sé si lo resuelve del todo, aun me estoy iniciando. Lo que si tengo 100% seguro es que he aislado el problema, ya que el resto del código me funciona perfectamente, lo he comprobado.